# Canada working permit number

Tags: canada, working

I will be working with a translation agency in Toronto. I will collaborate online and I live in Spain. They are asking me for a Canada permit working? Someone can tell me where to ask for it and what it is for since I will be working from home. I asked to my advisor but he doesn't know which number it is! Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You don't need a work permit if you are going to be living in Spain.

Comment: If you live in Spain for >183 days in a year, you will be a tax resident of Spain, and required to declare and pay Spanish taxes on your income earned from Canada.

Comment: You probably can't be an employee, but may have to be an independent contractor.